# Is a composite index row created for an entity if one of the properties is missing?

Tags: google-app-engine, composite-index

Is a composite index row created for an entity if one of the properties is missing ?

If half of the entities are missing one property will the index table be only half the size ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well according do the development console, it does not.

If a property required for the composite index is missing there is one write op less.

Also, if you remove a composite index definition from the index.yaml and refresh the datastore viewer all write ops needed are updated.